# Test specific androidmanifest file attributes and extra activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am using android studio 0.45 with gradle build to build my project. (gradle version 1.9). In my test folder I creating an extra activity that I don't want to be part of my release code. Where do I specify this activity in the Android Manifest. The gradle setup only allows for one AndroidManifest file as far as I can tell.

I am also using extra permissions in the test project to simulate phone calls that I don't need in my release code. How do I setup the manifest file so as to add permissions on a build specific mechanism...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should set up a product flavor for your test type, that includes the extra activity, and extra permissions in your AndroidManifest file. A flavor lets you have source files that are specific only to that flavor, and properties in the manifest that get merged together with the main manifest at build time.

Read the docs at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors and give it a shot.