# how to fix java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented

Tags: android, google-maps

I have this activity and i got the crash saied java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented how can i solve it?
it is like i make the activity impelements of something not implemented but i don't know how to fix it!
i faced this problem for many times and i don't know how to solve it!!

```
public class SelectEndPoint extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
private static String TAG = "MAP LOCATION";
Context mContext;
TextView mLocationMarkerText;
private LatLng mCenterLatLong;


/**
 * Receiver registered with this activity to get the response from FetchAddressIntentService.
 */
private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
/**
 * The formatted location address.
 */
protected String mAddressOutput;
protected String mAreaOutput;
protected String mCityOutput;
protected String mStateOutput;
EditText mLocationAddress;
TextView mLocationText;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
Toolbar mToolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_end_point);
    mContext = this;
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mLocationMarkerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));





    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
        // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
        if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
            // notify user
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
            mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;


            mMap.clear();

            try {

                Location mLocation = new Location("");
                mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                startIntentService(mLocation);
                mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

  //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  //        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
  //
 //        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
  //        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
 //        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        changeMap(mLastLocation);
        Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

    } else
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    try {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        if (location != null)
            changeMap(location);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}


protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            //finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void

changeMap(Location location) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Reaching map" + mMap);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    // check if map is created successfully or not
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        LatLng latLong;


        latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
        startIntentService(location);


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

}


/**
 * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
 */
class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
    public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    /**
     * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

        // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
        mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

        mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

        mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
        mStateOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

        displayAddressOutput();

        // Show a toast message if an address was found.
        if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
            //  showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));


        }


    }

}

/**
 * Updates the address in the UI.
 */
protected void displayAddressOutput() {
    //  mLocationAddressTextView.setText(mAddressOutput);
    try {
        if (mAreaOutput != null)
            // mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput+ "");

            mLocationAddress.setText(mAddressOutput);
        //mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
 * fetching an address.
 */
protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
    // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);

    // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

    // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
    intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);

    // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
    // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
    // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
    startService(intent);
}


      /* private void openAutocompleteActivity() {
    try {
        // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
        // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
        // the user to correct the issue.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                0 /* requestCode *//*).show();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
        // resolvable.
   /*     String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
 */

    /**
    * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its   result.
 */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   }}}
```

the error is :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method not implemented
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.zzarg(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.wneet.white.services.SelectEndPoint.buildGoogleApiClient(SelectEndPoint.java:252)
                                                                 at com.wneet.white.services.SelectEndPoint.onCreate(SelectEndPoint.java:118)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5581)
                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the error please.

Comment: AbstractMethodError is thrown for which method access? can you check logs

Comment: You are using Interface so you have to impliment interface abstract method

Comment: I edited the Question with logcat

Comment: Basically this error should be caught at compile time. At runtime, it might caused due to incompatitbly of the interface/abstract class.

Comment: how can i fix it plz? i still beginner in android

Comment: If you still have that problem, check your `build.gradle` file. All `com.google.android.gms` libraries should be in the same version (that was the case for me). I guess the newest would be the safest.

Answer (score 4):

Doing a clean of the project fixed a similar problem for me; it might work for you, too. Here is the error that *I* had:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SyncService]
                  Process: ie.eureka.moveitmobileandroid, PID: 22234
                  java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.util.List .manager.interfaces.WalkAroundCheckAnswers_YesNoManagerInterface.getListOfWalkAroundCheckAnswers_YesNoFromAttempt(ie.eureka.moveitmobileandroid.data.dao.WalkAroundCheckAttempt)"
                      at ie.eureka.moveitmobileandroid.services.networksync.SyncWalkAroundCheckAttempts.syncWithDatabase(SyncWalkAroundCheckAttempts.java:94)
                      at ie.eureka.moveitmobileandroid.services.networksync.SyncWalkAroundCheckAttempts.sync(SyncWalkAroundCheckAttempts.java:57)
                      at ie.eureka.moveitmobileandroid.services.SyncService.onHandleIntent(SyncService.java:32)
                      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've got this problem also. Somehow incremental build skipped the problematic file. Doing a rebuild fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have at dependencies different versions of play-services-base library and library which depends of it, for ex in my case it was due to

`implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"`

and

`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"`

and at top gradle file I had this:

```
allprojects {
  configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
     failOnVersionConflict()
     force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0"
   }
  }
}
```

to fix it I just changed ver of  `play-services-base` at top-level gradle file

```
...
force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case in `release` build I got a message like "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "a.b.c.d.e f.g.h.i.j$a.b (android.content.Intent)". I think, in line `startActivity(Intent(context!!, ParametersActivity::class.java))`.

What I made before: I added an activity "ParametersActivity" to `debug` branch, then switched to `release` and added an empty class "ParametersActivity". See [Using Non-Production Activity for Testing with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024537/using-non-production-activity-for-testing-with-android-studio) and [Use a set of class and resource only in debug mode with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442405/use-a-set-of-class-and-resource-only-in-debug-mode-with-gradle). I wanted to add this activity only in `debug` build and open it when testing.

Probably I made a mistake somewhere, but I put "ParametersActivity" not in `release` branch, but in `main`. So, a program compiled and launched and raised this exception. Then I moved this empty class from `main` to `release`, rebuilt, the exception disappeared.

Comment: also, check for which build are you using

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too. In my case I had to change the following:

- compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
- compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
- compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
- compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
- compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

to:

- compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
- compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
- compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
- compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
- compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'

it helped me to avoid the error.