# How to change URL and see push-token in release version

Tags: android, token, settings

I have a `release` version of an app and want to change a URL of a server (REST API), so that a tester could switch between production and test API. I also want to see `token` and Firebase `push-token` for this device and account. Also want to show logs after restarting of the app, because it can crash (if possible).

[image]

I can create an activity with these parameters. It can be opened after tapping several times on one TextView, for instance. It is not bad, but a user theoretically can reproduce and open the activity himself.

I can write a URL in Firebase Remote Config. Because the tester also has access to FRC, he can change the URL there and restart the app with new URL. It's a bit more difficult than changing in the activity.

I can create an activity only in test `release` version, so that in production `release` version it cannot be launched (this activity won't exist in AndroidManifest in production `release`).

What variant to prefer?

Comment: Well, IMO the last variant is best. However - can the Firebase token be switched in the runtime? In retrofit you can easily switch between clients, but can you switch between Firebase release/test tokens? Maybe you will have to register two tokens at once (if possible) and then lock/unlock test depend of the state of the app

Comment: @MariuszBrona, thank you! Agree. Firebase push tokens are long-living (usually until reinstall the app / wipe data).

Comment: I think you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024537/using-non-production-activity-for-testing-with-android-studio

Comment: @ShaluTD, thank you for searching! I didn't see it.

Comment: @ShaluTD, you are right, currently I am working on it.